# How to get entity type in EntityFramework when TPH inheritance model is used

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We use Table Per Hierarchy (TPH) to store inherited entities in EF6.1 (code first). Internally EF uses column Discriminator to keep the type of entity.

I can retrieve specific entity types using `OfType<>()` extension. I can even check the type of entity using `is` operator. But I cannot figure out how to retrieve entity type itself. We have hierarchy of several entities and I need to retrieve only few properties (I don't want to load whole entities) but need to select also the entity type. The current solution is like below. It is suboptimal. Is there a way how to get the type in a better way?

```
return DbSet.Where(o => o.Id == id)
    .SelectMany(o => o.BaseTransactions
    .Where(o => !(o is X00Transaction)))
    .Select(o => new TransactionInfoDto
    {
        TransactionId = o.Id,
        Amount = o.Amount,
        TransactionType =
            o is X01Transaction
                ? LoanDetailTransactionType.X01
                : o is X02Transaction
                    ? LoanDetailTransactionType.X02
                    : o is X03Transaction
                        ? LoanDetailTransactionType.X03
                        : o is X04Transaction
                            ? LoanDetailTransactionType.X04
                            : o is X05Transaction
                                ? LoanDetailTransactionType.X05
                                : LoanDetailTransactionType.X06,
    });
```

Comment: I had the same problem and forced to save the `LoanDetailTransactionType` in the entity as well. You can also materialize the query, then perform additional `Select` (using Linq-to-Objects) that will fill-in `TransactionType` using `typeof(x)`.

Comment: @haim770 Thanks for response - 1) storing additional column as workaround would work, 2) As I don't select entity (only few columns) I can't get its type using `typeof`. Anyway, does it mean there's no way to get the type using EF? - that's what I'm expecting but wanted to ask if I missed something or there was some nice trick..